# C++ => No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Tags: c++

I have a simple student project and I need some help. I have got a message with some kind of an error that i can't fix. Please help me with a solution. The project is in C++. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct V
{
    char name;
    list <V> to_v;
};

list <V> graph_v;
set <char> PoseteniVarhove;

list <V> ::iterator ukaz(char name)
{
    list <V> ::iterator retukaz = (list <V> ::iterator) NULL; // <-- ERROR HERE
    for (list <V> ::iterator it = graph_v.begin(); it != graph_v.end(); it++)
        if ((*it).name == name)
            retukaz = it;
    return retukaz;
}

void MakeGraph()
{
    int n, br;
    V v;
    list <V> ::iterator it;
    char name;

    do
    {
        cout << "Broy varhove(1..26): "; cin >> n;
    } while (n < 1 || n > 26);

    graph_v.clear();

    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        v.name = (char)('A' + c);
        v.to_v.clear();
        graph_v.push_back(v);
    }

    for (it = graph_v.begin(); it != graph_v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Vrah " << (*it).name << endl;
        cout << "Kam kolko drugi varha ima nasocheni rebra? ";
        cin >> br;
        for (int k = 0; k < br; k++)
        {
            cout << "Rebro kam vrah #" << 1 + k << endl;
            cout << "Ime na varha('A'..'Z'): ";
            cin >> name;
            v.name = name;
            v.to_v.clear();
            v.to_v.push_back(*ukaz(name));
            (*it).to_v.push_back(v);
        }
    }
}

void PrintGraph()
{
    list <V> ::iterator it, it1;
    for (it = graph_v.begin(); it != graph_v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Ot vrah " << (*it).name << " kam varhove ";
        for (it1 = (*it).to_v.begin(); it1 != (*it).to_v.end(); it1++)
            cout << (*it1).name << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

bool Path(char beginVrah, char TekVrah, char Target)
{
    bool P = false;
    list <V> ::iterator uk, it;
    if (PoseteniVarhove.count(TekVrah) == 0)
    {
        uk = ukaz(TekVrah);
        PoseteniVarhove.insert(TekVrah);
        for (it = (*uk).to_v.begin(); it != (*uk).to_v.end(); it++)
        {
            if ((*it).name == Target)
                return true;
            else
                if ((*it).name != beginVrah && !P)
                    P = Path(beginVrah, (*it).name, Target);
        }
    }
    return P;
}

void Paths()
{
    int Count = 0;
    bool P;
    list <V> ::iterator it, it1;
    for (it = graph_v.begin(); it != graph_v.end(); it++)
        for (it1 = it; it1 != graph_v.end(); it1++)
            if (it != it1)
            {
                P = false;
                PoseteniVarhove.clear();
                if (Path((*it).name, (*it).name, (*it1).name))
                    P = true;
                PoseteniVarhove.clear();
                if (Path((*it1).name, (*it1).name, (*it).name) && P)
                {
                    cout << (*it).name << ' ' << (*it1).name << endl;
                    Count++;
                }
            }
    cout << "Obshto " << Count << " dvoyki" << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char ch[256];
    int choice;
    cout << "Graph" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << endl << "1. Vavezhdane na Graph" << endl;
        cout << "2. Izvezhdane na Grapha" << endl;
        cout << "3. Paths" << endl;
        cout << "4. Kray" << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "(1,2,3,4): ";
            cin >> ch;
            choice = atoi(ch);
        } while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            MakeGraph();
            break;
        case 2:
            PrintGraph();
            break;
        case 3:
            Paths();
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (choice < 4);
    return 0;
}
```

The following error appears:

> No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

MSVC points to `NULL` in the first line of the function `ukaz`.

Comment: One suggestion: Variable names and comments are supposed to support the readers of the program - the compiler don't care. I'm a reader of the program and I don't understand. When making a [mcve], take the time to translate both variables and plain text to English before posting at SO. It'll make it possible for more people to understand what's supposed to being going on in the program - and possibly to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A "NULL" value for an iterator is usually `.end()`. It's not entirely clear to me what `ukaz` means, but it looks like you're trying to do something similar to a find.

As such, if nothing is found, I'd return the `.end()` of your `list`. Note that this is also [what `std::find` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

> **Return value**
>   Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found.

If you want the last occurrence of the value, you can loop using reverse iterators and return immediately when you find something. That way you don't even need to temporary iterator at all. That could look like:

```
list <V> ::iterator ukaz(char name)
{
    for (list <V> ::iterator it = graph_v.rbegin(); it != graph_v.rend(); it++)
        if ((*it).name == name)
            return it;
    return graph_v.end(); // <-- default return val if nothing is found
}
```